# JavaEE Glassfish Authentication: Confirmation link in email, no password for login

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, jaas

I'm developing a JavaEE 7 application using the authentication mechanism of GlassFish. To register our users, we want to have a simple registration form that generates an email with a link. Upon clickin on that link, we'd like the user to be able to login and fill out his user profile. My question is: When clicking on the link, we don't have access to the users password (in clear text), which is of course somehow correct. Now we would like to login the user without a password, is this possible programatically with glassfish? Or do we have to modify our security realm (a modified version of a JDBC realm)?

The "forgot password" mechanism has the exact same requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would suggest for what you have specifically asked:

1. Write a custom login module or custom realm (cloud modify your existing one) [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/beabs/).
2. Write a servlet and map it only to the confirmation URLs.
3. In the servlet, extract the relevant portion of the URL.
4. Call [HttpServletRequest#login()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) passing the relevant portion of the URL as username.
5. Send a redirect and enjoy!

Note that the realm should be able to differentiate between "normal" logins and logins coming from the link servlet. You could do this by using UUIDs or based on a null password.

However, doesn't a confirmation link usually mean the final step in the registration process where you presumably modify your underlying datasource to activate the user and disable the link from further access?

In this case, your servlet should probably directly modify the datasource with EJBs, JPA, or whatever else, tell the user their account has been enabled and send them to the login form.